# C# OpenTK GLSL Crashing on attempting to render

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

I've been trying to implement GLSL into my program, however given that i have never used GLSL before, i decided I would try following a tutorial. Unfortunately following tutorials aren't my forte, and I am stuck here with my program crashing when 'RenderTerrain()' is called (in the second line of code of the function (GL.DrawElements))

Now this obviously all the code in the program, there is A LOT more, there's no chance any of you would go through 20k lines to find my problem :P But if you need to ask questions about any of it, please comment :)

So my question simply is, is there anything wrong with this code? Why would it be crashing?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK;

namespace HoardOfUpgrades
{
    public class Shaders
    {
        private static string TerrainVertexShaderText = @"

            #version 140

            // object space to camera space transformation
            uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;            

            // camera space to clip coordinates
            uniform mat4 projection_matrix;


            // incoming vertex position
            in vec3 vertex_position;

            // incoming vertex normal
            in vec3 vertex_normal;

            // incoming vertex_color
            in vec3 vertex_color

            // transformed vertex normal
            out vec3 normal;

            void main(void)
            {
              //not a proper transformation if modelview_matrix involves non-uniform scaling
              normal = ( modelview_matrix * vec4( vertex_normal, 0 ) ).xyz;

              // transforming the incoming vertex position
              gl_Position = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * vec4( vertex_position, 1 );
            }

        ";

        private static string TerrainFragmentShaderText = @"

            #version 140

            precision highp float;

            const vec3 ambient = vec3( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 );
            const vec3 lightVecNormalized = normalize( vec3( 0.5, 0.5, 2 ) );
            const vec3 lightColor = vec3( 1.0, 0.8, 0.2 );

            in vec3 normal;

            out vec4 out_frag_color;

            void main(void)
            {
              float diffuse = clamp( dot( lightVecNormalized, normalize( normal ) ), 0.0, 1.0 );
              out_frag_color = vec4( ambient + diffuse * lightColor, 1.0 );
            }

        ";

        public static int TerrainFragmentShaderHandle, TerrainVertexShaderHandle, TerrainProgramHandle, ProjectionMatrixLocation, ModelviewMatrixLocation, TerrainNormHandle, TerrainPosHandle, TerrainColorHandle, TerrainIndicesHandle, TerrainIndiceCount;

        public static void Load(Vector3[] position, Vector3[] normals, Vector3[] colors, int[] indices)
        {
            LoadShaders();
            LoadProgram();

            LoadVertexPositions(position);
            LoadVertexNormals(normals);
            LoadVertexColors(colors);
            LoadIndexer(indices);
        }

        static void LoadProgram()
        {
            TerrainProgramHandle = GL.CreateProgram();

            GL.AttachShader(TerrainProgramHandle, TerrainVertexShaderHandle);
            GL.AttachShader(TerrainProgramHandle, TerrainVertexShaderHandle);

            GL.LinkProgram(TerrainProgramHandle);
        }

        static void LoadShaders()
        {
            TerrainVertexShaderHandle = GL.CreateShader( ShaderType.VertexShader );
            TerrainFragmentShaderHandle = GL.CreateShader( ShaderType.FragmentShader );

            GL.ShaderSource(TerrainVertexShaderHandle, TerrainVertexShaderText);
            GL.ShaderSource(TerrainFragmentShaderHandle, TerrainFragmentShaderText);

            GL.CompileShader(TerrainVertexShaderHandle);
            GL.CompileShader(TerrainFragmentShaderHandle);
        }

        private static void QueryMatrixLocations()
        {
            ProjectionMatrixLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(TerrainProgramHandle, "projection_matrix");
            ModelviewMatrixLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(TerrainProgramHandle, "modelview_matrix");
        }

        public static void SetModelviewMatrix(Matrix4 matrix)
        {
            GL.UniformMatrix4(ModelviewMatrixLocation, false, ref matrix);
        }

        public static void SetProjectionMatrix(Matrix4 matrix)
        {
            GL.UniformMatrix4(ProjectionMatrixLocation, false, ref matrix);
        }

        private static void LoadVertexPositions(Vector3[] data)
        {
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out TerrainPosHandle);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, TerrainPosHandle);
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                new IntPtr(data.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.BindAttribLocation(TerrainProgramHandle, 0, "vertex_position");
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);
        }

        private static void LoadVertexNormals(Vector3[] data)
        {
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out TerrainNormHandle);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, TerrainNormHandle);
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                new IntPtr(data.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.BindAttribLocation(TerrainProgramHandle, 1, "vertex_normal");
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);
        }

        private static void LoadVertexColors(Vector3[] data)
        {
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out TerrainColorHandle);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, TerrainColorHandle);
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                new IntPtr(data.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.BindAttribLocation(TerrainProgramHandle, 1, "vertex_color");
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);
        }

        private static void LoadIndexer(int[] data)
        {
            TerrainIndiceCount = data.Length;

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out TerrainIndicesHandle);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, TerrainIndicesHandle);
            GL.BufferData<int>(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer,
                new IntPtr(data.Length * sizeof(int)),
                data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        }

        public static void RenderTerrain()
        {
            GL.UseProgram(TerrainProgramHandle);

            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, TerrainIndiceCount,
                DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.UseProgram(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of code must be included:

```
        GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
        GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
        GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
```

Arrays were enabled, they must be disabled to use the GL.DrawElements() function